# Redirect on enter press javascript (But form hardwired into plugin, so must use input class rather than ID)

Tags: javascript, redirect, search, enter

So I am using a plugin called FacetWP for wordpress and creating a front end search. I would like the search input to redirect when I press enter. The search input is called a facet.

```
<?php echo facetwp_display( 'facet', 'search'); ?></div> <!-- Search input-->
```

The search input in HTMl looks like this, but I cannot edit it

```
<input type="search" class="facetwp-search" placeholder="">
```

Therefore I must call it by class rather than ID since I cannot add an ID

So far I have

```
<script>
$("#facetwpsearch").keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == '13')
{
function fwp_redirect() {
var query = FWP.build_query_string();
window.location.href = '/program-filter/?' + query;
}
});
<script>
```

Help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `$("#facetwpsearch")` - The `#` makes it look for an element by id. Also, in the html your class ha a `-`, here it doesn't. You want something more like `$(".facetwp-search")`

Comment: Heres my new code with your fixes: @neilsimp1

   `<script>$(".facetwp-search").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == '13')
    {
    function fwp_redirect() {
    var query = FWP.build_query_string();
    window.location.href = '/program-filter/?' + query;
    }
    });
    </script>`

However, does not trigger a search.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will just declare a function when enter is pressed, instead calling it.

It should be something like:

```
<script>
function fwp_redirect() {
   FWP.parse_facets();
   FWP.set_hash();
   var query = FWP.build_query_string();
   window.location.href = '/program-filter/?' + query;
}

$(".facetwpsearch").keydown(function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == '13') {
      fwp_redirect();
   }    
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a working solution :

```
<script>
    function fwp_redirect() {
        FWP.parse_facets();
        FWP.set_hash();
        var query = FWP.build_query_string();
        window.location.href = '<?php echo get_permalink(get_page_by_path( 'documents')); ?>/?' + query;
    }
    // redirect on "enter" key press
    jQuery('body').on('keyup', '.facetwp-search', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == '13') {
            fwp_redirect();
        }  
    });
</script>
```